# Extract token from response url - Spotify API

Tags: php, api, curl, token, spotify

I'm using this code to get a token from Spotify's Web API:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
$method = 'POST';

$credentials = "{Client ID}:{Client Secret}";

$headers = array(
        "Accept: */*",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent: runscope/0.1",
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials));
$data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

That results in this showing up in the browser:

```
{"access_token":"{token}","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

Great! But how do I extract "{token}" from the response and use it as a parameter in a request to the API? For example in the request to https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists which needs the token in the header field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the JSON:

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

Then you'll have an array with the values.

```
$token = $response['access_token'];
```

Also, you're missing a necessary option to obtain the response in this way:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

If not defined, you will get a boolean value instead of the response.

Comment: I added those two lines at the very bottom then put "echo $token;" after that, to verify that "$token" is the value I want, but it doesn't show up in my browser. What am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Do `var_dump($response);` before and after `json_decode`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get it right. I don't really need to show the token value in the browser. I want to extract {token} from the response and use it as a value in my calls to the API. Exactly where in my code should I put your two original lines and how can I verify that it's working? Could you put your rows of code in my code?
Thanks!

Comment: `var_dump` is only to debug your code and verify that it's working. The two answer's lines should be put after `$response = curl_exec($ch);` What do you see with `var_dump`?

Comment: Here's the code when I've added your lines: [http://codeshare.io/u9aap](http://codeshare.io/u9aap)
It gives me the same result as mention in original question, but with **bool(true) int(1)** after it.

Comment: It gives me an error now. Did I put the "var_dumps" and everything at the right place?

Comment: So forget the last comment. You may have to close curl after `curl_exec`: `curl_close($ch);`. What happen if you echo the response before `json_decode`?

Comment: Then it only echoes **bool(true)**. See updated code at [http://codeshare.io/CCHpV](http://codeshare.io/CCHpV).

Comment: Just use `$token = $response['access_token'];` and `echo $token;` Remove the `var_dump` lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out Manolo! It works great!

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

use this line too before your curl execute then it gives you proper json