# How to get Spotify api access token without asking user to login?

Tags: php, spotify, access-token, spotify-app

Coding in PHP, I try to initialize Spotify API, without using redirect uri, just using client_id and client_secret.
I try the code below : [Extract token from response url - Spotify API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519788/extract-token-from-response-url-spotify-api)  but I get a NULL result

I wonder if If I can access token without asking user to login (cf. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow)

Comment: If you could do that, I wouldn't feel too confident in Spotify's Privacy Policies.

Comment: It's OK. Access tokens not connected to specific users can be used to access endpoints related to playlists and Browse, and it also gives the application higher rate limits as opposed to making unauthenticated calls.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use the [Client Credentials flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow). However, remember that in most endpoints doesn't make sense unless the access token is connected to a user. I believe the are [PHP wrappers](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/#wrappers) which helps you make the request to get the access token using this flow.

Comment: can i play song in ios without Login or can i login using api i mean no ui for login in flow,i have premium account.

Answer (score 0):

```
     private static String getBearerToken()
        {
            String fetchUrl = getSiteUrl(playlistId);

            String html2 = fetchHtml(fetchUrl);

            Document document2 = Jsoup.parse(html2);
            Element ele = document2.getElementById("session");
            String session = ele.html();
            JSONObject tokens = new JSONObject(session);

            final String accessToken = tokens.getString("accessToken");
            return accessToken;
        }

private static String getSiteUrl(final String playlistId)
    {
        return "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/"+playlistId;
    }

private static String fetchHtml(final String urlstr)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlstr);
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            return new String(urlConnection.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Like here: https://github.com/BeatEngine/spotify-playlist-extractor-bpm

Set this on api urls:

```
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("client-token", "");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("authorization", " Bearer " + bearerToken);
```

As I found out, it's not important to set a correct client-token if you have the auth-token.