# Spotify Web API - Requests without Token Authentication

Tags: authentication, token, spotify

I have been playing around with Spotify's web api, so I can catalogue my music playlist etc.

I have been using Ajax to send requests to fetch playlist tracks with my Auth token in the header. I am trying to find a way around using a token; I've had a look around and but I am yet to find any information on performing this type of request without a token.

I'm hoping there is a way since I'm only fetching public playlists, thus being already viewable to anyone.

If this isn't possible, I'm guessing the only way to achieve something like this would be to generate an authentication token?

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I don't understand why it isn't possible to fetch this public data without an auth token ... or is it in place to stop flooding/spamming etc.?

As always, all help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is a way to use the API without user login.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322294/10570318

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a token to perform calls to Spotify

https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2017/01/27/removing-unauthenticated-calls-to-the-web-api/

Comment: Yes, this a **_very_** old question which was made when I did not have any experience with APIs/Backend development.