# Can I use Spotify Audio Features API without Spotify account?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, spotify

I'm trying to use "tempo" parameter for audio tracks by Spotify API.

I found that following web API (Get Audio Features for a Track) can return "tempo" data which I want.

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-audio-features/

However, it requires OAuth process.
Does it mean the user who uses my software to get tempo data must have Spotify account and login ?
Is there any other ways to get track tempo data without Spotify account ?

Answer (score 0):

No, a user of your software does not need to have a Spotify account, however, your software needs to be a registered Spotify Application and authenticate. See my answer here for a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38329729/1014870