# Is the Spotify search API no longer available without authentication?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, rest, spotify

For years I've been using Spotify's search API for various projects. It has always been available to use without authentication.

Example:
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=kanye%20west&type=track

Now starting just today it is responding with the following

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

I can't find anything stating that they've changed their search API, but the docs now say authentication is required.
[image]

It has previously stated that requests without an auth token would be rate limited. Now it says a token is required. Does anyone know if they've updated their API, or if this is a permanent thing? I find it hard to believe they would make such a drastic change to their API without notice.

Comment: I can't find a changelog for that change. https://jodal.no/2016/02/18/guide-to-poor-api-management/

Comment: Any changes you exceeded the rate limit?

Comment: Here is a way to have API access without user login:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322294/10570318

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They did update their API. Bummer.

https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2017/01/27/removing-unauthenticated-calls-to-the-web-api/

---

You can find details on how to migrate your unauthorized calls here:

https://developer.spotify.com/migration-guide-for-unauthenticated-web-api-calls/