# Is it possible to fetch a public spotify playlist without user authorization?

Tags: node.js, spotify

I need to be able to get the tracks in a public spotify playlist without user authorization. I was reading through the official docs and wasn't able to find anything about public playlists. Do you have any idea if it is possible and if yes, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Here is a way to do this without login
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322294/10570318

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid the answer is no. You need a `Client ID and Client Secret`.
Please visit https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/app-settings/

Comment: Yeah I get that my application needs a `Client ID and Client Secret`, however I'm more referring to the end user authorization part of spotify: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/ as a public playlist (imo) shouldn't need an authorized user